# PackagesNotFoundError: cudatoolkit=11.1.0 when installing pytorch

Tags: anaconda, conda

I get the installation command from the https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/. When I run the command:
`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1.0 -c pytorch`
I get the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudatoolkit=11.1.0

Current channels: like

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Then I have tried the following commands one by one:

```
(base) eslam@scholar:~$ conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

```
(base) eslam@scholar:~$ install cudatoolkit=11.1.0
install: missing destination file operand after 'cudatoolkit=11.1.0'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

```
(base) eslam@scholar:~$ conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.1.0
```

Get the same output as above.

```
(base) eslam@scholar:~$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/eslam/anaconda3
```

How can I fix this problem, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, the installation command I get is

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch`

cuda version is 11.0, not 11.1.0. Try the above.

Answer (score 47):

you need to use `-c conda-forge` for newest installs. From official site the command is:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

https://pytorch.org

Comment: This one worked for me. Remember to remove the "cpuonly"-version before you do that, if it was installed before.

Comment: This worked for me. FWIW, as of 2021-05-21, pytorch.org instructions were the following, which failed. Replacing "-c nvidia" with "-c conda-forge"(above)  did the trick.

NOTE: 'nvidia' channel is required for cudatoolkit 11.1
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Comment: I got the following error with that:  
`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudatoolkit=11.1`

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia -c conda-forge`

Answer (score 2):

You can [search `cudatoolkit` in anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=cudatoolkit) and find the channel that has your arch and version. In my case, I was installing PyTorch 1.8.1 under Windows but apparently the `nvidia` channel mentioned on the front page of PyTorch doesn't contain any packages for Windows, so I had to switch to `conda-forge`, where cudatoolkit 11.1 can be found (e.g., from the search result above).