# pytorch not using gpu instead it is using cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to run a pytorch code in gpu. Cuda version 11.7 is installed in my system.
Steps i followed to run my file in GPU :

1. Created conda environment
2. Installed pytorch using the following command
   `conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch` (as my code has some dependency,i am using these versions)
   Then while i am running the code , it is not using GPU

   torch.cuda.is_available() is giving false.

Can anyone help me out with this? what else is required to successfully run my file in gpu.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ use the command in the link that supports gpu

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder Hiii, i am getting this error. PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch-cuda=11.0

Comment: see answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589421/packagesnotfounderror-cudatoolkit-11-1-0-when-installing-pytorch

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder still getting same error